# Hadoop - failed redirect for container

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new with hadoop and have been trying to learn to run a mapreduce example in the hadoop 2.7.1 jar. I use the following command to do so
bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount input output

The job starts but fails with the following error

```
Failed redirect for container_1439014904092_0001_02_000001


Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.


Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1439014904092_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
15/08/08 11:55:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

I did try to go through a couple of links on stackoverflow and google but couldn't find the actual reason in detail for this error and neither the resolution. Has anyone got this error before ? What is the exact reason for the same and resolution for this error ?

Comment: is it a single node cluster.. ? what does jps return?

Comment: @sonic- yes it is a single node cluster. I was trying to run this example on my laptop in psuedodistributed mode.

Comment: @Kumar- could you guide me to the exact path of the detailed log. I thought I pasted the complete log. I went to the cluster link in (Resource Manager)and went to the failed section. Also the stack trace appeared on the command line in yarn console.

Comment: what does jps command return?

Comment: @sonic- here is what jps command returns
C:\deploy\hadoop-2.7> jps
7904 Jps
2128 DataNode
5940 NodeManager
5832 NameNode
6056 ResourceManager

Comment: @all- Anyone any comments or help ?

Comment: did you get any solution ??

Comment: @Sazzad - I don't recall the exact solution for this as it has been quite sometime. But one thing which I clearly recall was the my approach to get hadoop running was incorrect, I was looking at various articles available on google. After I got tired up, I followed BUILDING.txt word by word which is available in hdfs home directory, I could easily run hadoop. You can give it a try, thanks!!